# LLVM: add linker directives to LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, coff

How can I add linker directives found in a COFF (MSVC object file) with LLVM using LLVM IR? Or is there another tool that can add these directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM 5.0

```
!llvm.linker.options = !{ !0 }

!0 = {!"/DEFAULTLIB:flang.lib", !"/DEFAULTLIB:flangrti.lib", !"/DEFAULTLIB:ompstub.lib"}
```

LLVM 4.0

```
!llvm.module.flags = {!0}

!0 = !{i32 6, !"Linker Options", !1}
!1 = !{!2, !3}
!2 = !{!"/DEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib"}
!3 = !{!"/DEFAULTLIB:oldnames.lib"}
```